# php fileuploader basenam

Tags: php

Hye guys, I have created jquery ajax file uploader, but I have one problem with it which is the server side, it will over-ride any file with the same name And Im going to generate a random number, which should be different to another one but so the code for my uploader is

```
<?php
$target_path = "/var/www/vhosts/grubber.co.nz/httpdocs/developer/_social_development/uploads/blog/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['img']['name']); 


if (file_exists($target_path)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
    $target_path = "/var/www/vhosts/grubber.co.nz/httpdocs/developer/_social_development/uploads/blog/" . basename( $_FILES['img']['name']); 
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['img']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Question, I want it to check if a file exsits and if it does generate a random number and add it to the name? if not just continues and writes the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution could be to prepend filename with some unique number.

You can use uniqid() function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

```
<?php
$target_path = "/var/www/vhosts/grubber.co.nz/httpdocs/developer/_social_development/uploads/blog/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['img']['name']); 


if (file_exists($target_path)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
    $target_path = "/var/www/vhosts/grubber.co.nz/httpdocs/developer/_social_development/uploads/blog/" .uniqid().basename( $_FILES['img']['name']); 
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".basename( $_FILES['img']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't work it just pops out a error "The file  exists
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function uniqueid() in /var/www/vhosts/grubber.co.nz/httpdocs/developer/_social_development/json/uploadblog.php on line 8"