# How can I add a random name to images being uploaded to my website?

Tags: php, image, random, upload, rename

so I'm in the process of making a .gif uploading website, and this is my code for "upload_file.php".

```
        <?php
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5242880)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("i/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "i/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "i/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

How can I add a random image name? Preferably 6-8 digits of only #0-9. That way the image name is simple instead of being specific to capital letters etc. Please be as specific with directions as possible, because I'm still learning PHP, and that's one of the main reasons I'm making this website.

P.S. Bonus points if you can tell me how to redirect straight to the image without the page that shows the file info.

Comment: u can look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php. the question is here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986070/php-fileuploader-basenam

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

How about making the random name based on the time of upload?

```
20121130184908.jpeg
```

That's what would be the moment I wrote that (utc-0800) as 2012-11-30 18:49:08

If there is heavy uploading, then perhaps the milliseconds should be included too.

Comment: But is there a way just to generate a rondom number? I don't want a super long number.

Answer (score 1):

**Call this function to generate your file name

```
function  makeFileName($size=6, $path="/", $extension=".gif"){
    //if you give a path, don't forget the slash at end

    $root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];        
    $name = rand(0, str_repeat(9, $size));
    $name = $root.$path.str_pad($name, 8,  0, STR_PAD_LEFT).$extension;
    while(is_file($name)){
        makeFileName();
    }
    return $path.$name; 
}
echo makeFileName();

//makeFileName(6, ".png") Will create a png file name with 6 digits
```

Edit :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], makeFileName(6, "/your/dir/", ".png"));
```

Comment: It looks like that works, but how do I go about attaching that name to the file? I just got:
[http://imgur.com/0yiHw](http://imgur.com/0yiHw)

Comment: @KenTurner If your problem is solved, please close the thread by accepting the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use [uniqid()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) i think it will give you what you need